# SQL - How to pick the latest date out of group rows that have same primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

So I have a table as follows:

```
  item_ID   |   item_date   |   status
-1147446003 |   2018-07-21  |  Assigned
-1147446003 |   2018-07-22  |  Completed
-1147446003 |   2018-07-23  |  Closed
-1147446001 |   2018-07-21  |  Assigned
-1147446001 |   2018-07-22  |  Updated
-1147446001 |   2018-07-22  |  Completed
```

What I'd like to do is create a query that will give me back only the newest date for an item_ID. So a result like this:

```
  item_ID   |   item_date   |   status
-1147446003 |   2018-07-23  |  Closed
-1147446001 |   2018-07-22  |  Completed
```

I've tried using a subquery that I'd join with an left outer join with a MAX() on the date, but it doesn't work.  I even tried doing:

```
date = MAX(item_date) over (partition by item_ID)
```

But that just brings the row entry I want at the top of the results, while it still contains all the other rows for that item_ID.  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Just a note - primary keys are unique by definition, in SQL Server and every SQL database. A group of rows should never have the same primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which database you are using but most of them support the ROW_NUMBER analytical function and you can use below query to get the desired results -

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_DATE, STATUS FROM
(
SELECT 
ITEM_ID, ITEM_DATE, STATUS,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_ID ORDER BY ITEM_DATE DESC) AS RNK
FROM TABLE_NAME
)X
WHERE RNK=1;
```

Comment: This is the query that gave me exactly what I needed. TY!

Answer (score 2):

First, `item_id` is not a primary key if it has duplicates.  This is a matter of terminology, but you should understand what "primary key" means.

A simple way that doesn't use subqueries is:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by item_id order by item_date desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rank` to get the desired row.

```
select item_id,item_date,status
from (select t.*,rank() over(partition by item_id order by item_date desc) as rnk
      from tbl t
     ) t
where rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers above should work, but if the SQL that you are using do not support analytical functions, this should work.

```
SELECT a.item_ID,
    a.item_date,
    a.status
from [your_table_here] a
JOIN (
  SELECT item_ID 
    MAX(item_date) AS max_item_date
  FROM [your_table_here]
  GROUP BY 1
  ) b
ON a.item_ID = b.max_item_date
AND a.item_ID = b.item_ID
```